# Registering to Steam doesn't work

Tags: steam

I tried to register with Steam on the following page for about 3 days now, and it doesn't work from Mac Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Am I the only one experiencing this behaviour?

https://store.steampowered.com/join/?

Maybe the JavaScript on this page is broken? I chose a username that has not been taken, and also entered all other information and clicked the I agree thingy. Please tell me if someone else can register or if there is another way to register with Steam (for example via some API, or PlayStation or something similar).

Comment: do you block cookies? did you try using the [steam client](http://cdn.steampowered.com/download/SteamInstall.msi)? It also has a register function

Comment: Could you give more detail then just "it doesn't work"?

Comment: sorry, -1 for your lack of detail and feedback. "it just doesn't work" is the worst kind of problem report I can imagine... If you edit in more information, please @notify me so I can take that back

Comment: I love this otherwise "useless" question. On my computer, it alternates between repeatedly verifying that I'm a human, and telling me that registration fails and to try again later. (I registered first time on my wife's Mac, so I'm pretty sure it's not me)

Comment: Even *nicer* was that the Steam client told me my name was taken (as I had thought it would be), where the web rego claimed availability.

Comment: Same issue that Stephen has. Now I'm pretty sure the website's backend that checks if the account name has already been taken is broken somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install [Steam Client](http://cdn.steampowered.com/download/SteamInstall.msi) and register from there.

Comment: This worked. Just as information: the account name I chose wasn't free in the client (now chose another one), but the website showed me that it was free. Maybe it was an issue that the check for free-ness of the account name doesn't work correctly.

Comment: 9 years later and I got the same problem LOL.

Comment: But now the app uses web form too, so it's not working properly in the app neither.